monaca cordova app InAppBrowser plugin does not work
I'm trying to use InAppBrowser plugin in monaca.io I'm installing it in default monaca dashboard, they do have this plugin ready ver 5.0.0. When I install it and try to call it within project (when cordova app is loaded) using: cordova.InAppBrowser.open()
I get error undefined is not an object evaluating cordova.InAppBrowser.open I have 2 more plugins installed and those works fine. What I'm missing here? I have this plugin installed in debugger and testing it there, but I tried to compile app too (same result)
Thank you.

It seems I was using cordova 7.1.0 which was not compatible with plugins I wanted to use. I had to go back to 6.2.0 for now
